# Regular expression - replace if character before it not x

Tags: regex, sed

noob question.

I would like to replace all the `@` by `”,”` if the character before `@` is not `”`

To increment this command `cat foo.csv | sed 's/@/","/g'`

Comment: Use this : `sed 's/[^"]@/","/g' foo.csv`.

Comment: I'd use `sed -r 's/(^|[^"])@/\1","/g' foo.csv` to also match `@` at the start.

Comment: from my understanding of the question, I come up with this: `sed 's/\(^\|[^"]\)@/\1","/g'`

Comment: Useless use of `cat`!! `sed` reads from the file you give it.

Comment: I would suggest to never use `cat file | command`. Also, google UUOC just for fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
sed -r 's/(^|[^"])@/\1","/g'
```

where `(^|[^"])` is a group matching either the start of a line or a character other than `"`. The `\1` is a backreference to the Group 1 (either an empty string or a char matched with a `[^"]` bracket expression).

For an alternative syntax without `-r`, see [Kent's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860520/regular-expression-replace-if-character-before-it-not-x#comment63178297_37860520) (you will need to escape the special characters like `(`, `)`, `|` for them to behave as special regex metacharacters).